# Meaning of correlation coefficient

Tags: statistics

What does it mean, exactly, when it is said that:

If two variables $x$ and $y$ are correlated with correlation coefficient $\rho >0$ then $\rho^2$ of the variation in $x$ can be explained by the variation in y.

Is it something like:

Suppose we have two lists of variables $x_i$ and $y_i$. Let the variance of $y$ be $\sigma_y^2$ and the correlation between $x$ and $y$ be $\rho.$ Consider the best-fit line of least squares regression between them. Let $z(x_i)$ be this line of best fit. Consider the list of points $z(x_i)-x_i$. The variance of *this* list of points will be $\rho^2 \sigma_y^2$ (it will be smaller).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pearson Correlation Coefficient Interpretation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/333290/pearson-correlation-coefficient-interpretation)

Comment: @P.S.Dester No, not really. I am asking about the oft repeated phrase, "the square of the correlation coefficient explains the percentage of the variance that is explained by another variable." That question is not addressing that particular phrase at all.

Comment: Where did you read that phrase? It is well known that in PCA the eigenvalues of the *covariance* (not *correlation*!) matrix are variances whose sum is the total variance of the sum of the independent factors. Hence, what follows about explained percentage by those single eigenvectors? BTW: a mathematician should refrain from using the phrase "something like".

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3076842/321264

Comment: @KurtG. Something akin to that phrase is quite common in many referenes. The reason I use the phrase "something like" is that the precise nature of the phrase is rarely specified and often varies

Comment: @KurtG. See https://www.investopedia.com/terms/c/correlationcoefficient.asp "Nor does the correlation coefficient show what proportion of the variation in the dependent variable is attributable to the independent variable. That's shown by the coefficient of determination, also known as R-squared, which is simply the correlation coefficient squared." https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/45419/do-correlation-or-coefficient-of-determination-relate-to-the-percentage-of-value , https://www.sportsci.org/resource/stats/correl.html "The resulting statistic is known as variance explained"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can express $\ x\ $ as the sum
$$
x=\alpha y+z
$$
of two random variables, one of which (viz. $\ \alpha y\ $) is directly proportional to $\ y\ $ and the other of which (viz. $\ z\ $) is [*uncorrelated*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation#Correlation_and_independence) to $\ y\ .$  To achieve this, you have to choose $\ \alpha=\frac{\rho\sigma_x}{\sigma_y}\ .$ The variance $\ \sigma_x^2\ $ of $\ x\ $ is now the sum
$$
\sigma_x^2=\sigma_{\alpha y}^2+\sigma_z^2
$$
of a part (viz. $\ \sigma_{\alpha y}^2\ $) resulting from the "dependence" of $\ x\ $ on $\ y\ $, and a part (viz. $\ \sigma_z^2\ $) resulting from the "dependence" of $\ x\ $ on a variable uncorrelated to $\ y\ $. Since $\ \sigma_{\alpha y}^2=\rho^2\sigma_x^2\ $ and $\ \sigma_z^2=\big(1-\rho^2\big)\sigma_x^2\ $, then a proportion $\ \rho^2\ $ of the variance of $\ x\ $ comes from its "dependence" on $\ y\ $ and a proportion $\ 1-\rho^2\ $ from its "dependence" on a variable uncorrelated to $\ y\ $. I've put scare quotes around the word "dependence" here because the random variable $\ z\ $ is not necessarily *independent* of $\ y\ $.  If the distribution of $\ (x,y)\ $ is bivariate normal, however, then $\ z\ $ and $\ y\ $ *will* be independent, and the scare quotes become unnecessary.

Comment: The variable z is not necessarily *independent*, but it is *uncorrelated*, correct? (The relation z=|y| neatly shows an example of this).

Comment: You say, "you can express $x$ as the sum." Does this always hold? Is that fact trivial, or does it need to be demonstrated?

Comment: @Jbag1212 That answer said that $z$ is [*uncorrelated*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation#Correlation_and_independence) in the first sentence and gave a hint how to achieve this always. Further hint: with the given $\alpha\,,$ what is the covariance of $y$ and $z\,?$

Comment: ... when you define $z$ as $z:=x-\alpha y\,.$